# Как вызвать статический метод класса возврающающий экземляр для использования Unity?

Tags: c#, devexpress, unity-container

Есть базовый интерфейс`IViewModel` для всех моих `ViewModel`. Все `ViewModel` используют DevExpress POCO механизм:

```
public static EfCaseCollectionViewModel Create(IUnitOfWorkFactory<IDomainModelContextUnitOfWork> unitOfWorkFactory = null)
{
    return ViewModelSource.Create(() => new EfCaseCollectionViewModel(unitOfWorkFactory));
}
protected EfCaseCollectionViewModel(IUnitOfWorkFactory<IDomainModelContextUnitOfWork> unitOfWorkFactory = null)
        : base(x => x.Cases, unitOfWorkFactory ?? UnitOfWorkSource.GetUnitOfWorkFactory(),projection:t=>t.Where(x=>x.Removed==false))
{
}
```

Во `ViewModel` не используется без параметрический конструктор.

Unity контейнер я создаю при старте в статическом классе:

```
UnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
unityContainer.RegisterType<IViewModel, EfCaseCollectionViewModel>("CaseCollection");
```

Во `View`:

```
public EfCaseCollectionView(IUnityContainer container)
{
    this.DataContext = GetViewModel(container);
    InitializeComponent();
}

private IViewModel GetViewModel(IUnityContainer container)
{
    if (container.IsRegistered<IViewModel>("CaseCollection"))
    {
        return container.Resolve<IViewModel>("CaseCollection");
    }
    return container.Resolve<IViewModel>();
}
```

Но без конструктора без параметров это не работает. (`MissingMethodException:'System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`). Как правильно использовать Unity в этой ситуации?

Comment: посмотрите похожий вопрос: [How to create objects using a static factory method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576761/how-to-create-objects-using-a-static-factory-method)

Comment: если вы нашли ответ на свой вопрос, стоит добавить собственный ответ с описанием решения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо за  [ссылку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576761/how-to-create-objects-using-a-static-factory-method), помогла как пища для размышлений.

Честно, часть вопроса связанная с Exception не связана с основной частью тем что я просто не уследил что в CodeBehind'е View UserControl нету конструктора без параметров.

По поводу основной части. Сделал так:

```
public static readonly UnityContainer UnityContainer = new UnityContainer();

public static void Resolve()
{
    UnityContainer.RegisterType<IViewModel>("CaseCollection", new InjectionFactory(c => EfCaseCollectionViewModel.Create()));
}
```

Этот метод вызывается в App.xaml.cs

А в View Так:

```
public EfCaseCollectionView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = GetViewModel(Bootstrapper.UnityContainer);
}

private IViewModel GetViewModel(IUnityContainer container)
{
    if (container.IsRegistered<IViewModel>("CaseCollection"))
        {
            return container.Resolve<IViewModel>("CaseCollection");
        }
        //if not found, get default factory
        return container.Resolve<IViewModel>();
}
```

Я не уверен что решение правильное, но мою текущую задачу оно выполнило.

Comment: стоит добавить в ответ саму ссылку :)